# tablet problems with webGl; shows fine on PC

Tags: javascript, webgl

I can't get this webgl rippling effect to happen on touch screens: http://onestopdesktop.com/D2/ apparently the problem has nothing to do with the touch functions after all. something in the webgl coding itself is preventing it from operating on touch devices. I uncovered that when I changed the SOURCEFLOW default to 4 which causes a single ripple to flow on PC's on screen load. however, nothing at all happens on touch devices on load. it does work perfectly in the Chrome touch device emulator. my test touch devices (iPad 2 and 3, iPhone5,  Android Asus, are all up to date OS and browser wise and are fully webgl capable.

I really love this beautiful water rippling code that I found in a tutorial at *Webgl Academy*, and I'm trying to help a student get this effect to work with her website.

below is the code I'm using. I added the touch event stuff to it.

```
var main=function() {
var CANVAS=document.getElementById("your_canvas");
CANVAS.width = window.innerWidth;
CANVAS.height = window.innerHeight;
var GL = CANVAS.getContext("webgl", {antialias: false, alpha: false});
var POINTER_X=0.5, POINTER_Y=0.5;
CANVAS.addEventListener("mousemove", waterMove);
CANVAS.addEventListener("touchstart", waterTouch);
CANVAS.addEventListener("touchmove", waterMove2);
CANVAS.addEventListener("touchend", waterStop);
function waterMove(event) {
event.preventDefault();
POINTER_X=(event.clientX-CANVAS.offsetLeft)/CANVAS.width;
POINTER_Y=1-event.clientY/CANVAS.height;
 }; 
function waterMove2(event) {
event.preventDefault();
POINTER_X=(event.changedTouches[0].clientX-CANVAS.offsetLeft)/CANVAS.width;
POINTER_Y=1-event.changedTouches[0].clientY/CANVAS.height;
 };     
 function waterTouch(event) {
event.preventDefault();
SOURCEFLOW = 4;
POINTER_X=(event.touches[0].clientX-CANVAS.offsetLeft)/CANVAS.width;
POINTER_Y=1-event.touches[0].clientY/CANVAS.height;
 };
 function waterStop(event) {
event.preventDefault();
SOURCEFLOW = 0;
POINTER_X=(event.changedTouches[0].clientX-CANVAS.offsetLeft)/CANVAS.width;
POINTER_Y=1-event.changedTouches[0].clientY/CANVAS.height;
 };
 SOURCEFLOW=4;
 CANVAS.addEventListener("mouseup", function(event) { event.preventDefault();SOURCEFLOW = 0;       } , false);
CANVAS.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) { event.preventDefault();SOURCEFLOW = 4; } , false);
//enable texture float
var EXT_FLOAT = GL.getExtension('OES_texture_float') ||
GL.getExtension('MOZ_OES_texture_float') ||
GL.getExtension('WEBKIT_OES_texture_float');

/*========================= PARAMETERS ========================= */

var SIMUSIZEPX=512; //GPGPU simulation texture size in pixel
var SIMUWIDTH=1;    //Simulation size in meters
var GPGPU_NPASS=6; //number of GPGPU pass per rendering
var WATER_DEEP=0.01;          //mean height of water in meters
var RENDERING_FLOOR_SIZE=1; //size of the water floor texture in meters

/*========================= RENDERING SHADERS ========================= */
var vertSrc_render="\n\
attribute vec2 position;\n\
\n\
varying vec2 vUV;\n\
\n\
void main(void) {\n\
gl_Position = vec4(position, 0., 1.);\n\
vUV=0.5*(position+vec2(1.,1.));\n\
}";


var fragSrc_render="\n\
precision mediump float;\n\
\n\
uniform float H; //water deep (meters)\n\
uniform float L; //simulation size (meters)\n\
uniform float l; //ground texture tile size (meters)\n\
uniform sampler2D sampler;\n\
uniform sampler2D sampler_normals;\n\
\n\
varying vec2 vUV;\n\
\n\
const vec3 light=vec3(1.,1.,1.);\n\
const vec4 color_sky=vec4(60./255., 90./255., 150./255., 1.);\n\
const float n=1./1.33;\n\
\n\
void main(void) {\n\
vec4 water=texture2D(sampler_normals, vUV);\n\
vec3 water_normal=water.rgb+vec3(0.,0.,1.);\n\
float water_height=water.a;\n\
\n\
vec3 I=vec3(0.,0.,1.);               //incident vector\n\
vec3 R = refract(I, water_normal, n); //refracted vector\n\
\n\
float k=(water_height+H)/R.z;         //k so that M=kR belongs to the water floor\n\
vec3 M=k*R;                           //belongs to the water floor\n\
vec2 uv=(vUV*L-M.xy)/l;               //texture coordinates of the water floor\n\
vec4 color_floor=texture2D(sampler, uv);\n\
\n\
float F=water_normal.z; //Fresnel reflexion coefficient = (I.N)\n\
\n\
vec4 color=mix(color_sky, color_floor, 0.6+F*0.3);\n\
\n\
vec3 lightDir=normalize(light-vec3(L*(vUV-vec2(0.5,0.5)), water_height));\n\
\n\
float lightPow=clamp(pow(dot(lightDir, water_normal),4.),1., 1.3);\n\
\n\
gl_FragColor=lightPow*color;\n\
}";

/*================= SHALLOW WATER EQUATION SHADERS ================== */

var fragSrc_water="\n\
precision mediump float;\n\
\n\
uniform float dt, H, b, g, epsilon;\n\
uniform float scale;\n\
uniform vec2 mouse;\n\
\n\
uniform float sourceRadius, sourceFlow;\n\
uniform sampler2D sampler_water, sampler_normals;\n\
\n\
varying vec2 vUV;\n\
\n\
void main(void) {\n\
\n\
vec4 water_t  = texture2D(sampler_water, vUV);\n\
float h       = water_t.r;\n\
vec2 uvSpeed  = water_t.gb;\n\
\n\
vec2 dx=vec2(epsilon, 0.);\n\
vec2 dy=vec2(0., epsilon);\n\
float du_dx=(texture2D(sampler_water, vUV+dx).g-texture2D(sampler_water, vUV-   dx).g)/(2.*scale);\n\
float dv_dy=(texture2D(sampler_water, vUV+dy).b-texture2D(sampler_water, vUV- dy).b)/(2.*scale);\n\
\n\
vec3 normals=texture2D(sampler_normals,vUV).xyz;\n\
\n\
//we add 1 to Nz because RGB = (0,0,0) -> Normal = (0,0,1)\n\
vec2 d_uvSpeed = -dt * (g * normals.xy/(normals.z+1.) + b*uvSpeed);\n\
\n\
float d_h = -dt * H * (du_dx + dv_dy);\n\
\n\
float dSource = length(vUV-mouse);\n\
\n\
d_h += dt * sourceFlow * (1. - smoothstep(0., sourceRadius, dSource));\n\
gl_FragColor = vec4(h+d_h, uvSpeed+d_uvSpeed, 1.);\n\
}";

/*================= TEXTURE COPY SHADERS ================== */

var fragSrc_copy="\n\
precision mediump float;\n\
\n\
uniform float scale;\n\
uniform sampler2D sampler;\n\
\n\
varying vec2 vUV;\n\
\n\
void main(void) {\n\
float dxy=1./scale;\n\
vec4 waterData = texture2D(sampler, vUV);\n\
vec4 waterDataAvg=(texture2D(sampler, vUV+vec2(dxy,0.))\n\
+.5*texture2D(sampler, vUV+vec2(dxy,dxy))\n\
+texture2D(sampler, vUV+vec2(0.,dxy))\n\
+.5*texture2D(sampler, vUV+vec2(-dxy,dxy))\n\
+texture2D(sampler, vUV+vec2(-dxy,0.))\n\
+.5*texture2D(sampler, vUV+vec2(-dxy,-dxy))\n\
+texture2D(sampler, vUV+vec2(0.,-dxy))\n\
+.5*texture2D(sampler, vUV+vec2(dxy,-dxy)))/6.;\n\
\n\
gl_FragColor = mix(waterData, waterDataAvg, 0.3);\n\
}";

/*================= NORMALS SHADERS ================== */

var fragSrc_normals="\n\
precision mediump float;\n\
\n\
uniform sampler2D sampler;\n\
uniform float epsilon, scale; //horizontal scale in meters\n\
varying vec2 vUV;\n\
\n\
vec3 getPoint(float x, float y, vec2 uv){\n\
float h = texture2D(sampler, uv+vec2(x,y)).r; //water height\n\
return vec3(x*scale,y*scale,h);\n\
}\n\
\n\
void main(void) {\n\
vec3 points[4];\n\
points[0]=getPoint(-epsilon,0., vUV);\n\
points[1]=getPoint(0.,-epsilon, vUV);\n\
points[2]=getPoint(epsilon ,0., vUV);\n\
points[3]=getPoint(0. ,epsilon, vUV);\n\
\n\
vec3 normal=normalize(cross(points[1]-points[3], points[2]-points[0]));\n\
\n\
//We substract 1 to Nz because Normal = (0,0,1) -> RGB = (0,0,0)\n\
normal.z-=1.;\n\
\n\
float height=texture2D(sampler, vUV).r;\n\
gl_FragColor=vec4(normal, height);\n\
}";

//compile a shader :
var get_shader=function(source, type, typeString) {
var shader = GL.createShader(type);
GL.shaderSource(shader, source);
GL.compileShader(shader);
if (!GL.getShaderParameter(shader, GL.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
  alert("ERROR IN "+typeString+ " SHADER : " + GL.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
  return false;
}
return shader;
};

//build a shader program :
var get_shaderProgram=function(vertex_source, fragment_source, typeStr){
var shader_vertex=get_shader(vertex_source, GL.VERTEX_SHADER, typeStr+" VERTEX");
var shader_fragment=get_shader(fragment_source, GL.FRAGMENT_SHADER, typeStr+" FRAGMENT");

var shader_program=GL.createProgram();
GL.attachShader(shader_program, shader_vertex);
GL.attachShader(shader_program, shader_fragment);

GL.linkProgram(shader_program);
return shader_program;
};


//final rendering shader program
var SHP_VARS={};
var SHP_RENDERING=get_shaderProgram(vertSrc_render, fragSrc_render, "RENDER");

SHP_VARS.rendering={
H: GL.getUniformLocation(SHP_RENDERING, "H"),
L: GL.getUniformLocation(SHP_RENDERING, "L"),
l: GL.getUniformLocation(SHP_RENDERING, "l"),
sampler: GL.getUniformLocation(SHP_RENDERING, "sampler"),
sampler_normals: GL.getUniformLocation(SHP_RENDERING, "sampler_normals"),
position: GL.getAttribLocation(SHP_RENDERING, "position")
};
var SHP_WATER=get_shaderProgram(vertSrc_render, fragSrc_water, "WATER");

SHP_VARS.water={
dt: GL.getUniformLocation(SHP_WATER, "dt"),
H: GL.getUniformLocation(SHP_WATER, "H"),
b: GL.getUniformLocation(SHP_WATER, "b"),
g: GL.getUniformLocation(SHP_WATER, "g"),
mouse: GL.getUniformLocation(SHP_WATER, "mouse"),
sourceFlow: GL.getUniformLocation(SHP_WATER, "sourceFlow"),
sourceRadius: GL.getUniformLocation(SHP_WATER, "sourceRadius"),

epsilon: GL.getUniformLocation(SHP_WATER, "epsilon"),
scale: GL.getUniformLocation(SHP_WATER, "scale"),

sampler_water: GL.getUniformLocation(SHP_WATER, "sampler_water"),
sampler_normals : GL.getUniformLocation(SHP_WATER, "sampler_normals"),

position: GL.getAttribLocation(SHP_WATER, "position")
};

var SHP_COPY=get_shaderProgram(vertSrc_render, fragSrc_copy, "COPY");

SHP_VARS.copy={
scale : GL.getUniformLocation(SHP_COPY, "scale"),
sampler: GL.getUniformLocation(SHP_COPY, "sampler"),
position: GL.getAttribLocation(SHP_COPY, "position")
 };
var SHP_NORMALS=get_shaderProgram(vertSrc_render, fragSrc_normals, "NORMALS");

SHP_VARS.normals={
sampler: GL.getUniformLocation(SHP_NORMALS, "sampler"),
scale: GL.getUniformLocation(SHP_NORMALS, "scale"),
epsilon: GL.getUniformLocation(SHP_NORMALS, "epsilon"),
position: GL.getAttribLocation(SHP_NORMALS, "position")
};


 /*========================= THE QUAD ========================= */
//POINTS :
var quad_vertex=[
-1,-1, //first summit -> bottom left of the viewport
1,-1,  //bottom right
1,1,   //top right
-1,1   //top left
 ];

var QUAD_VERTEX= GL.createBuffer ();
GL.bindBuffer(GL.ARRAY_BUFFER, QUAD_VERTEX);
GL.bufferData(GL.ARRAY_BUFFER,new Float32Array(quad_vertex),GL.STATIC_DRAW);

//FACES :
var quad_faces = [0,1,2, 0,2,3];
var QUAD_FACES= GL.createBuffer ();
GL.bindBuffer(GL.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, QUAD_FACES);
GL.bufferData(GL.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array([0,1,2, 0,2,3]),GL.STATIC_DRAW);


/*========================= THE TEXTURE ========================= */

var renderingImage=new Image();
renderingImage.src='ressources/waterFloor.jpg';
var renderingTexture=GL.createTexture();
GL.pixelStorei(GL.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
GL.bindTexture(GL.TEXTURE_2D, renderingTexture);
GL.texImage2D(GL.TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL.RGBA, 1, 1, 0, GL.RGBA, GL.UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
new Uint8Array([255, 0, 0, 255]));
renderingImage.onload=function() {
GL.bindTexture(GL.TEXTURE_2D, renderingTexture);
GL.texParameteri(GL.TEXTURE_2D, GL.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL.LINEAR);
GL.texParameteri(GL.TEXTURE_2D, GL.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL.LINEAR);
GL.texImage2D(GL.TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL.RGBA, GL.RGBA, GL.UNSIGNED_BYTE, renderingImage);
};

/*====================== RENDER TO TEXTURE ====================== */

//GPGPU WATER RTT :
var fb_water=GL.createFramebuffer();
GL.bindFramebuffer(GL.FRAMEBUFFER, fb_water);

var texture_water=GL.createTexture();
GL.bindTexture(GL.TEXTURE_2D, texture_water);
GL.texParameteri(GL.TEXTURE_2D, GL.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL.NEAREST);
GL.texParameteri(GL.TEXTURE_2D, GL.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL.NEAREST);
GL.texParameteri( GL.TEXTURE_2D, GL.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL.CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
GL.texParameteri( GL.TEXTURE_2D, GL.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL.CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
GL.texImage2D(GL.TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL.RGBA, SIMUSIZEPX, SIMUSIZEPX, 0, GL.RGBA, GL.FLOAT, null);

GL.framebufferTexture2D(GL.FRAMEBUFFER, GL.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL.TEXTURE_2D, texture_water, 0);

//COPY RTT :
var fb_copy=GL.createFramebuffer();
GL.bindFramebuffer(GL.FRAMEBUFFER, fb_copy);

var texture_water_copy=GL.createTexture();
GL.bindTexture(GL.TEXTURE_2D, texture_water_copy);
GL.texParameteri(GL.TEXTURE_2D, GL.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL.NEAREST);
GL.texParameteri(GL.TEXTURE_2D, GL.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL.NEAREST);
GL.texParameteri( GL.TEXTURE_2D, GL.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL.CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
GL.texParameteri( GL.TEXTURE_2D, GL.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL.CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
GL.texImage2D(GL.TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL.RGBA, SIMUSIZEPX, SIMUSIZEPX, 0, GL.RGBA, GL.FLOAT, null);
GL.framebufferTexture2D(GL.FRAMEBUFFER, GL.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL.TEXTURE_2D,   texture_water_copy, 0);

//NORMALS RTT :
var fb_normals=GL.createFramebuffer();
GL.bindFramebuffer(GL.FRAMEBUFFER, fb_normals);

var texture_normals=GL.createTexture();
GL.bindTexture(GL.TEXTURE_2D, texture_normals);
GL.texParameteri(GL.TEXTURE_2D, GL.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL.NEAREST);
GL.texParameteri(GL.TEXTURE_2D, GL.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL.NEAREST);
GL.texParameteri( GL.TEXTURE_2D, GL.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL.CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
GL.texParameteri( GL.TEXTURE_2D, GL.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL.CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
GL.texImage2D(GL.TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL.RGBA, SIMUSIZEPX, SIMUSIZEPX, 0, GL.RGBA, GL.FLOAT, null);
GL.framebufferTexture2D(GL.FRAMEBUFFER, GL.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL.TEXTURE_2D, texture_normals,  0);


/*========================= INIT ========================= */

//WEBGL GENERAL INIT
GL.disable(GL.DEPTH_TEST);
GL.disable(GL.SCISSOR_TEST);
GL.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);


//SHADER PROGRAM RENDERING INIT
GL.useProgram(SHP_RENDERING);
GL.enableVertexAttribArray(SHP_VARS.rendering.position);
GL.uniform1f(SHP_VARS.rendering.H, WATER_DEEP);
GL.uniform1f(SHP_VARS.rendering.L, SIMUWIDTH);
GL.uniform1f(SHP_VARS.rendering.l, RENDERING_FLOOR_SIZE);
GL.uniform1i(SHP_VARS.rendering.sampler, 0);
GL.uniform1i(SHP_VARS.rendering.sampler_normals, 1);
GL.vertexAttribPointer(SHP_VARS.rendering.position, 2, GL.FLOAT, false,8,0) ;
GL.bindBuffer(GL.ARRAY_BUFFER, QUAD_VERTEX);
GL.bindBuffer(GL.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, QUAD_FACES);
GL.disableVertexAttribArray(SHP_VARS.rendering.position);


//SHADER PROGRAM GPGPU WATER INIT
GL.useProgram(SHP_WATER);
GL.uniform1i(SHP_VARS.water.sampler_water, 0);
GL.uniform1i(SHP_VARS.water.sampler_normals, 1);

//WE SIMULATE A SQUARE WATER SURFACE SIDE MEASURING 2 METERS
GL.uniform1f(SHP_VARS.water.g, -9.8);       //gravity acceleration
GL.uniform1f(SHP_VARS.water.H, WATER_DEEP);  //mean height of water in meters
GL.uniform1f(SHP_VARS.water.b, 0.001);       //viscous drag coefficient
GL.uniform1f(SHP_VARS.water.epsilon, 1/SIMUSIZEPX); //used to compute space derivatives
GL.uniform1f(SHP_VARS.water.scale, SIMUWIDTH/SIMUSIZEPX);

GL.uniform1f(SHP_VARS.water.sourceRadius, 0.04); //percentage of the surface which is flowed  by the source

GL.enableVertexAttribArray(SHP_VARS.water.position);
GL.vertexAttribPointer(SHP_VARS.water.position, 2, GL.FLOAT, false,8,0) ;
GL.bindBuffer(GL.ARRAY_BUFFER, QUAD_VERTEX);
GL.bindBuffer(GL.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, QUAD_FACES);
GL.disableVertexAttribArray(SHP_VARS.water.position);


//SHADER PROGRAM TEXTURE COPY INIT
GL.useProgram(SHP_COPY);
GL.uniform1f(SHP_VARS.copy.scale, SIMUSIZEPX);
GL.uniform1i(SHP_VARS.copy.sampler, 0);
GL.enableVertexAttribArray(SHP_VARS.copy.position);
GL.vertexAttribPointer(SHP_VARS.copy.position, 2, GL.FLOAT, false,8,0) ;
GL.bindBuffer(GL.ARRAY_BUFFER, QUAD_VERTEX);
GL.bindBuffer(GL.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, QUAD_FACES);
GL.disableVertexAttribArray(SHP_VARS.copy.position);


//SHADER PROGRAM NORMALS INIT
GL.useProgram(SHP_NORMALS);
GL.uniform1i(SHP_VARS.normals.sampler, 0);
GL.uniform1f(SHP_VARS.normals.epsilon, 1/SIMUSIZEPX); //used to compute space derivatives
GL.uniform1f(SHP_VARS.normals.scale, SIMUWIDTH);

GL.enableVertexAttribArray(SHP_VARS.normals.position);
GL.vertexAttribPointer(SHP_VARS.normals.position, 2, GL.FLOAT, false,8,0) ;
GL.bindBuffer(GL.ARRAY_BUFFER, QUAD_VERTEX);
GL.bindBuffer(GL.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, QUAD_FACES);
GL.disableVertexAttribArray(SHP_VARS.normals.position);

/*========================= RENDER LOOP ========================= */

var old_timestamp=new Date().getTime();
var old_timestamp=0;
var animate=function(timestamp) {
var dt=(timestamp-old_timestamp)/1000; //time step in seconds;
dt=Math.min(Math.abs(dt), 0.017);
old_timestamp=timestamp;

GL.clear(GL.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


for (var i=0; i<GPGPU_NPASS; i++) {

  //COPY
  GL.bindFramebuffer(GL.FRAMEBUFFER, fb_copy);
  GL.useProgram(SHP_COPY);
  GL.viewport(0.0, 0.0, SIMUSIZEPX, SIMUSIZEPX);
  GL.enableVertexAttribArray(SHP_VARS.copy.position);
  GL.bindTexture(GL.TEXTURE_2D, texture_water);
  GL.drawElements(GL.TRIANGLES, 6, GL.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
  GL.disableVertexAttribArray(SHP_VARS.copy.position);

  //GPGPU PHYSICAL SIMULATION :
  GL.bindFramebuffer(GL.FRAMEBUFFER, fb_water);
  GL.useProgram(SHP_WATER);
  GL.enableVertexAttribArray(SHP_VARS.water.position);
  GL.activeTexture(GL.TEXTURE1);
  GL.bindTexture(GL.TEXTURE_2D, texture_normals);
  GL.activeTexture(GL.TEXTURE0);
  GL.bindTexture(GL.TEXTURE_2D, texture_water_copy);
  if (!i) {
    GL.uniform2f(SHP_VARS.water.mouse, POINTER_X, POINTER_Y);
    GL.uniform2f(SHP_VARS.water.touch, POINTER_X, POINTER_Y);
    GL.uniform1f(SHP_VARS.water.sourceFlow, SOURCEFLOW);
    GL.uniform1f(SHP_VARS.water.dt, dt/GPGPU_NPASS);
  };
  GL.drawElements(GL.TRIANGLES, 6, GL.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
  GL.disableVertexAttribArray(SHP_VARS.water.position);

  //NORMALS :
  GL.bindFramebuffer(GL.FRAMEBUFFER, fb_normals);
  GL.useProgram(SHP_NORMALS);
  GL.enableVertexAttribArray(SHP_VARS.normals.position);
  GL.bindTexture(GL.TEXTURE_2D, texture_water);
  GL.drawElements(GL.TRIANGLES, 6, GL.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
  GL.disableVertexAttribArray(SHP_VARS.normals.position);

} //end for GPGPU_NPASS


//RENDERING :
GL.bindFramebuffer(GL.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
GL.useProgram(SHP_RENDERING);
GL.enableVertexAttribArray(SHP_VARS.rendering.position);
GL.viewport(0.0, 0.0, CANVAS.width, CANVAS.height);
GL.activeTexture(GL.TEXTURE1);
GL.bindTexture(GL.TEXTURE_2D, texture_normals);
GL.activeTexture(GL.TEXTURE0);
GL.bindTexture(GL.TEXTURE_2D, renderingTexture);
GL.drawElements(GL.TRIANGLES, 6, GL.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
GL.disableVertexAttribArray(SHP_VARS.rendering.position);

GL.flush();
window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
 };

animate(new Date().getTime());
};
```

Thanks for any help!!!!

Comment: `POINTER_X` and `POINTER_Y` are assigned by an event handler listening to the `mousemove` event, you'll need to implement your own event handler for touch events to get the coordinates.

Comment: I already have: CANVAS.addEventListener("touchmove", waterMove2); function waterMove2(event) {
event.preventDefault();
    POINTER_X=(event.changedTouches[0].clientX-CANVAS.offsetLeft)/CANVAS.width;
    POINTER_Y=1-(event.changedTouches[0].clientY/CANVAS.height);
  }; p.s, it works in the Chrome iPad simulator.